# Where to write AWS signing code

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to validate my AWS keys for S3 storage for my Django project. So I've found [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html) from the offical site. It shows various Python code but it doesn't say where to write it? What file do I put this code in?

Comment: Are you asking how to sign AWS API requests? The answer, almost always, is to use an AWS-provided SDK. In the case of Python, that's boto3.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to have a system configuration file that lives outside of version control, and then import it into settings.py or your equivalent thereof.